# Muti-language list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a product list which store english description for each field.

How can i implement/architect multi-language feature to provide same product in french ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [variatons](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262055.aspx). It should help you plan your multilingual web sites.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements, but a common way to do this is with language translation files ( the common extension is .po or .mo ) used by the GNU gettext project, and supported across multiple platforms.  Essentially, what you store in the database is a key, and depending on the specific language you are displaying, you pull the correct value based on that key.

Using .po files also means you can use a language file editor like http://www.poedit.net/

There are a few implementations of gettext, for most platforms / languages.
Here is a reference for php:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

or if you're using the zend framework
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html

In general, just store the msgid, and use gettext to retreive the right value depending on the selected language.

An example:
 - create a directory 'locale'
   and sub directories for the 2 letter language code

locale/en
   locale/fr

and create file for each page you wish to translate
   locale/en/default.po
   locale/fr/default.po

in the english file you create string definitions using the standard syntax

```
msgid "site-main-welcome"
msgstr "Hello!  Welcome to our site"
```

in the french po file

```
msgid "site-main-welcome"
msgstr "Salut!  bienvenue à notre website"
```